# Solve a system for the existence or absence of variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, finite-fields

I have a series of triplets. Only some of them have to be added to a triplet constant to get the result. The result, the constant and the series of triplets are all known and with fixed values.

For example, let's say we have $A = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$, $B$, $...$ to $Z = (z_1, z_2, z_3)$, and only 5 of them will satisfy the equation. We could have, for example: $B + G + J + M + W$, added to the constant:

$\begin{pmatrix} C_{1} \\ C_{2} \\ C_{3} \end{pmatrix}$

that would give the expected result, let's say:

$\begin{pmatrix} 50 \\ 100 \\ 150 \end{pmatrix}$

This looked like a very classic linear system to solve, using Gaussian elimination, so I tried to do it in this way. However, it doesn't seem to work, as I don't want to solve for the values of the triplets $A, B, ...$, but for their existence or not, as only one combination of triplets will satisfy the equation.

How could I do this?

EDIT: added `finite-fields` tag since the maths will probably take place in $GF(256)$, as I work with bytes and XOR (though I guess it shouldn't change the logic of the solving).

Comment: since the constant is known, it can always be deducted from the result, isn't it ?

Comment: @GCab Indeed, it can. Should I be noticing something with this change?

Comment: Getting rid of the constant would make your question more general and clear. But of course it does not change the substance of the problem, which is quite interesting.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, the problem resembles that of decoding an error correcting code. There are a number of fixed vectors, and we know that the sum of five (or less) of those vectors is to match a given vector (such as the syndrome of the received vector that we hope to contain at most five errors). The bad news is that in general that problem is hard (IIRC known to be in one of those nasty NP classes), in small cases something can be done. Anyway, it looks like you need to describe the problem more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

So, incorporating the constant into the result, we have
$$
x_1 \,A_1  + x_2 \,A_2  +  \cdots  + x_n \,A_n  = S\quad \left| \begin{array}{l}
 \;A_1 ,A_1 , \cdots ,A_n ,S \in \left\{ {\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {a_{k,1} }  \\  {a_{k,2} }  \\   {a_{k,3} }  \\
\end{array}} \right)} \right\}given \\ 
 \,x_1 ,x_2  \cdots ,x_n  \in \left\{ {0,1} \right\}\;unknown \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$
and the problem is to determine the $x_k$ knowing a priori that the solution is unique.

*Hint about the solution*

Now, start with a simple example, take the A's to be just scalars and take just two of them $A_1 = 2, \; A_2 = 3$ .
The equation is
$$
x_1 \,A_1  + x_2 \,A_2  = S \in \left\{ {0,2,3,5} \right\}
$$

Divide both sides by a positive integer $q$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \frac{{x_1 \,A_1  + x_2 \,A_2 }}{q} = x_1 \frac{{\,A_1 }}{q} + x_2 \,\frac{{A_2 }}{q} =  \\ 
  = x_1 \left( {\left\lfloor {\frac{{\,A_1 }}{q}} \right\rfloor  + \frac{{A_1 \bmod \left( q \right)}}{q}} \right)
 + x_2 \,\left( {\left\lfloor {\frac{{\,A_2 }}{q}} \right\rfloor  + \frac{{A_2 \bmod \left( q \right)}}{q}} \right) =  \\ 
  = \left\lfloor {\frac{S}{q}} \right\rfloor  + \frac{{S\bmod \left( q \right)}}{q} \\ 
 \end{array}
$$

Being the $x_k$ equal to $0$ or $1$, we can write
$$
x_1 \left( {A_1 \bmod \left( q \right)} \right) + x_2 \,\left( {A_2 \bmod \left( q \right)} \right) \equiv S\quad \left( {\bmod q} \right)
$$

and if we take $q$ to be in turn $A_1$ and $A_2$ we can establish the system
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x_1  \cdot 0 + x_2  \cdot \,1 \equiv S\left( {\bmod 2} \right) \\ 
 x_1  \cdot 2 + x_2  \cdot 0 \equiv S\left( {\bmod 3} \right) \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$
which is a $2 \times 2$ system, with a matrix that has a determinant not null (full rank),
and therefore has a unique solution for whichever set of numbers are given as the known column.
Therefore if S admits the on-off  representation in the $A_k$, that should be the solution of the system.
In fact we get
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
   {S = }  &  0 & 2 & 3 & 5  \\
   {x_1  = }  &  0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\
   {x_2  = }  &  0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\
\end{array}
$$

The above until $\gcd (A_1, A_2)=1$, which ensures that the system has full rank,
also considering  [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

I suppose you can take on  from here.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll see how I can adapt this to my problem.